# How do I fix this "Permission denied" error I get every time I execute aptitude?

Tags: aptitude

When I execute, for example, `aptitude search ruby2.5`, I get the following errors as first lines of the output. (It's the same error message repeated twice.)

> E: Error saving configuration file - apt_dumpcfg (13: Permission denied)
>   E: Error saving configuration file - apt_dumpcfg (13: Permission denied)

I take the configuration file used from apt_dumpcfg is not writable from the account I am using. I don't get which configuration file is, and where is located.

I google both apt_dumpcfg and apt_dumcfg(), but I didn't find any specific information I could use to fix the error, like the following links (which are the first links I get when searching *apt_dumpcfg*).

- [Ubuntu Manpage: Aptsh - interactive APT shell](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/aptsh.1.html)
- [Matthijs' Blog – Just my personal blog where I ramble](https://matthijs.hoekstraonline.net/)
- [UniFi - USG Advanced Configuration – Ubiquiti Networks Support](https://help.ubnt.com/hc/en-us/articles/215458888-UniFi-USG-Advanced-Configuration)
- [Solved: Can I see Edge router with UNIFI controller? - Ubiquiti ...](https://community.ubnt.com/t5/UniFi-Routing-Switching/Can-I-see-Edge-router-with-UNIFI-controller/td-p/1198071)

How do I fix that error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to fix the ownership of `~/.aptitude` and its contents:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.aptitude
```

Comment: It was this. Strangely, I reinstalled Linux Mint, and I don't get anymore that error, even if I first install a package with aptitude before using aptitude for other purposes (for example, running `sudo aptitude install ruby2.5` before `aptitude search ruby2.5-gtk3`).